# I need to convert a 3 column array into a square matrix?

Tags: matrix, square

I am looking to convert my data to a square matrix:

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate which programming language you want to accomplish this in?

Comment: hey
it's with Python, if you have any idea please !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say your input is a list; you can then convert it to a list of lists (i.e., a proxy to a matrix) with list comprehension:

```
>>> x = [0, 5, 10, 5, 0, 2, 10, 2, 0]
>>> [x[3*k:3*k+3] for k in range(3)]
[[0, 5, 10], [5, 0, 2], [10, 2, 0]]
```

To help you parse the line: you are building a list by iterating over `k` from 0 to 2, where each element will be a slice of `x` that starts from index `3*k` and ends at index `3*k+3`. Thus, your list is `[x[0:3], x[3:6], x[6:9]]`.

That said, it's much better to use numpy for all such needs. There, you would do:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array([0, 5, 10, 5, 0, 2, 10, 2, 0])
>>> x.reshape(3, 3)
array([[ 0,  5, 10],
       [ 5,  0,  2],
       [10,  2,  0]])
```

The `reshape()` function converts your 1D array into the requested 2D matrix.